# How to find an x y coordinate that is d distance away from a given point on slope m?

Tags: haskell

We are trying to define a Haskell function that gives the coordinates x, y given a starting point (x0, y0), distance from the starting coord, and slope of the line that goes through both points. Any ideas?

It will probably have a signature of

`endPoint :: (Double, Double) -> double -> double -> (Double, Double)`

How you would do this on paper is to use the distance formula (with the second point as variables/unknowns), which then gives you some ratio of the x and y for this new point, use that ratio as the substitution into the point-slope formula, which should give one of y and x, then plug that value into the formula again to get the x and y we don't have yet.

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29126138/calculate-distance-between-two-points-haskell), we can do the distance formula, but how do we deal with substitution? Is that possible in Haskell?

Comment: This sounds like a math problem. Solve it with paper and pencil and plug the result into your program, parameterized by whatever variables are appropriate.

Comment: This problem doesn't have a unique solution; it always has two solutions. How are you going to pick which one to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the definition of [slope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slope), this problem could be solved like this:

```
endPoint :: (Double, Double) -> Double -> Double -> (Double, Double)
endPoint (x0, y0) m d = (x0 + dx, y0 + dy)
  where theta = atan m
        dx = d * cos theta
        dy = d * sin theta
```

Here is an example about point (2,8) and (3,20):

```
*Main> endPoint (2,8) 12 (sqrt $ 12 * 12 + 1)
(3.000000000000001,20.0)
```